# Simplifying Summation of the Form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n+\alpha m)g(n-\alpha m)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, change-of-variable

I have come across a summation of the form;

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n+\alpha m)g(n-\alpha m)$$

Where $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\alpha\neq 0$. I want to separate these two summations by changing variables. My first idea was to define new variables, $i=n+\alpha m$, $j=n-\alpha m$. Then as $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}$, I thought that;

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n+\alpha m)g(n-\alpha m)
=
\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}f(i)g(j)
$$

Apparently this is incorrect however, as in the $\alpha = 1$ case, $i$ and $j$ are always either both even or both odd, leading to additional complications. With this in mind, I really can't see how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated, as would any general pointers on changing variables in sums. I understand the process for integrals, but haven't had to do it for a sum before.

Comment: Obviously the sum is depending on $\alpha$. You can see this easily when looking at $\alpha = 0$. Therefore your simplified form - if it exists - will definitely contain $\alpha$.

Comment: Good point. I also realised that I left out that $\alpha \neq 0$, and have edited accordingly. (This of course doesn't invalidate your point).

Comment: $\alpha = 0$ is only the most graphic example. Depending on the functions $f$ and $g$ this sum will always be depending on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the double sum is absolute convergent, then we can reorder the sum: Split the summation over $n$ by looking at resiude classes modulo $\alpha$. In fact, we have
$$\sum_{q=0}^{\alpha-1} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} f(q+\alpha(n+m)) g(q+\alpha(n-m)).$$
Note that
$$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_0 \times \mathbb{Z}_0 \cup  \mathbb{Z}_1 \times \mathbb{Z}_1, \quad \text{via} \ (n,m) \mapsto (n+m,n-m),$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_i = \{m \in \mathbb{Z} : m \equiv i \ \mathrm{mod} \ 2\}$, is a bijection. Thus the above sum is equal to
\begin{align}
 &= \sum_{q=0}^{\alpha-1} \Big( \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}_0^2}  f(q+\alpha n) g(q+\alpha m)+\sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}_1^2}f(q+\alpha n) g(q+\alpha m) \Big) \\
 &= \sum_{q=0}^{\alpha-1} \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \Big( f(q+2\alpha n) g(q+2\alpha m)+ f(q+\alpha+2\alpha n) g(q+\alpha+2\alpha m)\Big) \\
&= \sum_{q=0}^{2\alpha-1} \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} g(q+2\alpha m)f(q+2\alpha n)  \\
&= \sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 , m \equiv n \, \mathrm{mod} \ 2\alpha} g(m) f(n)
\end{align}

**Update:** We can deduce a smilar equality for rational $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$. Just write $\alpha =v/w$ with coprime $v \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $w \in \mathbb{N}$, then the sum is equal to
$$\sum_{h=0}^{w-1} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n+ \alpha h + v m) g(n-\alpha h -vm).$$
Hence, we can apply the previous result to conclude that the initial sum is given by
$$\sum_{h=0}^{b-1} \sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 , m \equiv n \, \mathrm{mod} \ 2v} f(n+\alpha h)g(m-\alpha h).$$

Comment: There was an error in the bijection argument. I have repaired the argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry, but I just realized this leads to another question, can anything be said for $\alpha$ a rational number? (And should I edit my original question to reflect this addition?). Thanks again!

Comment: You can add a second question to your original question. If $\alpha =a/b$ with coprime $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$ you may first decompose the summation over $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ by residue classes mod $b$ and then reduce the problem to the initial one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!